# How to run run bash code in a perl script

Tags: bash, perl

I have the following bash code which I want to run within a perl script. As a bash script the code runs without any error. But in the perl script it gives the error: Bad name after bash' at ./061_rewrite_aws.pl line 48.

```
system(' 'bash' '-c' <<'END_SHELL_CODE';
AWS_Base="/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.205,share=zmd-backup"
 pushd /home/zmd/AWS/AWS_DataDirs
 cp -R $AWS_Base/* ./
popd
'END_SHELL_CODE' ');
```

Assistance will be appreciated

Comment: You're trying to run this bash script with perl right?

```bash
AWS_Base="/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.205,share=zmd-backup";
pushd /home/zmd/AWS/AWS_DataDirs cp -R $AWS_Base/* ./;
popd;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's just some quoting errors with that line of perl.

1. `system` takes a list of strings as arguments, so I changed that quoting to be a list of strings.

   - Right now I think perl is parsing that line and expecting `bash` to be the name of some variable.
2. The here-doc formatting was off. I think the `;` after END_SHELL_CODE on the first line, and having `END_SHELL_CODE` in single quotes at the end didn't work with perl's formatting, so I removed that.

Something like this worked for me:

```perl
system('bash', '-c', <<'END_SHELL_CODE'
AWS_Base="/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.205,share=zmd-backup"
pushd /home/zmd/AWS/AWS_DataDirs
cp -R $AWS_Base/* ./
popd
END_SHELL_CODE
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much @GandhiGandhi, the code as per your modification works perfect. Thanks for your time and effort.